# Multiple DC/DC or single DC/DC + LDO

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, emc, interference

My FSAE team and I are developing the electronic boards for the car, like BSPD, TSAL, etc.

So far, we use a 24V battery for low voltage system with a single DC/DC 24V to 5V converter for each board, for a total of six.  For the purposes of this question, let's say each board consumes 10-50 mA. All the board are mounted close together, one on the top of the other.

My question is, since i'm not an expert on EMI and things like that, is whether it better to use one external single DC/DC, for example 24V to 9V, that is able to provide about 2-3A max, with a LDO 9V to 5V on each board.  The idea is that this would provide a more stable power supply to the boards (applying some input filter to the LDO) and to not generate problems with switching circuits one next to the other?

Does this make sense?

My question arises from the fact that the ambient of the car surely has interference with inverter of the motor and i would mitigate this kind of problem.

Comment: You cannot effectively develop a strategy for dealing with interference if you do not have a good idea of what the interference is. What are the frequencies of interest?  How do they couple into your sensitive components?  What is their power?

Comment: EMC is a holistic topic. There isn't much we can answer here I'm afraid, without at least a wiring diagram of the boards in question, and whatever they connect to; preferably, complete diagrams including schematics and the whole system. We also need to know the requirements: allowed emissions (if any, something functional at least?), expected immunity.

Comment: I have edited your question for clarity (less than I had to -- you put paragraph separators in the right place, but you need to give _two_ linefeeds for StackExchange to recognize the new paragraph).  Could you please check my edits and revise where you see fit?  While you're at it, while an electronics group should be expected to know what a DC/DC converter or an LDO regulator is, please define your other abbreviations -- FSAE, BSPD, and TSAL.

Comment: but it's not possible to have a generic answer? Better single DC/DC or multiple?

Comment: Having a separate converter on each board is kind of getting to the "point of load" concept and can have some advantages handling noise on the power bus, especially from one board coupling into another board, but this won't really help with radiated EMI. Your best strategy is to keep the interference from coupling back out of the inverter *close to the source* instead of trying to stop it at each endpoint.

Comment: Six boards at 50mA each adds up to 300mA; you're saying elsewhere you need 2 to 3 amps.  Does your question need clarification?

Comment: @TimWescott I went overboard with the numbers, just to be sure

Comment: @vir ok thank you. But now, one question: neglecting the inverter, disposing buck converters of the same type, model, and frequency next to each other, can create EM problems between the boards?

Comment: Possibly. The manufacturer may have specific guidance on this, either in the datasheet or in an app note/whitepaper.

Comment: A switched DC/DC followed by a LDO is a design meant to take out EMI generated by the switched DC/DC, not by the environment. Cars will have spikes and surges which need to be dealt with separately. Typically by using TVS on all inputs and providing a big bulk cap on the input to the switched DC/DC.

Comment: @vir unfortunately I didn't found anything about that

Comment: @Lundin thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

**Define a common 'Power supply':**

As i dont know much about the physical placement of the boards in the car, i assume, that they can spaced apart multiple meters (Some Cockpit I/O and rear axel monitoring e.g. - dont know if they exist).

Therefore, i would identifie **the maximum requirements** in your system.

Lets say, the device in the cockpit needs 5W max. but a power hungry "something-device" needs 25W -> this gives you 25W @ 24V +/- 20% for example.

Based on this i would develope a "common DC/DC stage". This includes:

- Line Filtering
- TVS/ESD protection
- Fusing / Current-Limiting
- Common 5V Output
- Output-Filtering etc.

I would then go on and test "the sh**" out of this circuit block. Make sure it meets all specification and test it deeply - spend some time here.

Afterwards, i would simply re-use this "building block" in all other boards.

To produce the different rails required for the logic (May vary between 3V3 only, 1V8/1V2, and so on...) i would use a LDO specific for the board in question.

**Tu use them in the car** i would go on and define "a standard connector" for your overall system. This can include more than VBAT/GND. For example:

- Diagnosis/programming port (3V3 UART e.g.) for "on the bench" tests

You can then simply generate your cable harness by routing one cable from the battery to all devices in a "multi-drop" configuration for power supply.

If you remove a control-unit to test/replace/what-ever it, you can use a "USB-C to 25W + UART converter - design it yourself :) ) to plug into your laptop on Race-day to use the diagnosis port and power the unit at the same time.

**EDIT:**

If you are smart, you can use the same style of connector in a different color (E.G. Orange for POWER/DIAG and Blue for In-Vehicle Communication - you could run four independant strings of CAN to connect different units together. Like: Real-critical goes on BUS-A, x/y/z on BUS-B and so on). Have a sharp eye towards companys like phoenix contact... The whole range of automotive goodies available via digikey.